# Flex-direction: column; not working in IE and Edge

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, microsoft-edge

I have a menu with list item displayed in a vertical list using `flexbox` and `flex-direction:column`.
It's working great in all browsers except for IE and Edge.

I tried tricks like adding display flex to the flex container but it's not working either.

Any ideas ?

Here's the website where the problem happens : http://lesdeuxvagues.com/demo

Click the plus button in the menu to see the problem

CSS:

```
ul{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Cool that you've fixed your issue but your question is useless now for other people because your website link is now not showing your issue anymore. 
In the future please paste minimal code reproducing your issue and not website link.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Yes i know! i couldn't figure out how to reproduce the issue with only minimal code, as I explained, the problem came from the framework's css.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out i just fixed the issue by adding `display:block;` to my list items. 
They had a `display:table-cell` from the foundation framework that might have caused this problem!